# Two services with same images should use different Dockerfiles

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am trying to build the two services with the same image, but two different Dockerfile. However Docker will always use only one Dockerfile for both, even though two have been defined:

```
version: '3.4'
services:
 serviceA: 
    image: myimage 
    build:
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
      context: ${project.basedir}/${project.artifactId}-docker/target
    depends_on:
      - serviceB 

 serviceB: 
    image: myimage
    build:
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile-cloud
      context: ${project.basedir}/${project.artifactId}-docker/target
```

Even though I also say dependsOn, running

```
docker-compose up -f docker-compose.yml
```

it only used the Dockerfile-cloud for both.

Comment: That doesn't really make sense; if the two images are built from different Dockerfiles then they can't really be the same image.  Why do they need to be "the same"; what happens if you just delete the `image:` lines entirely?

Comment: @DavidMaze you're right. I deleted the image lines and now it works! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I guess your problem is that you tag your image as `myimage` (using latest by default). So docker will build a first version of `myimage` with `Dockerfile`, then it'll build another version of `myimage` with `Dockerfile-cloud`, and in the end it will only use the latest version. This is why it will use Dockerfile-cloud for both. To fix it remove `image: myimage` or do something like:

```
serviceA: 
  image: myimage:serviceA
...
serviceB: 
  image: myimage:serviceB
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're building the two containers' images from different Dockerfiles, they can't really be the same image; they'll have different content and metadata.

Compose is capable of assigning unique names for the various things it generates.  Unless you need to do something like `docker-compose push` built images to a registry, you can generally just omit the `image:` line.  The two containers will use separate images built from their own Dockerfiles, and the Compose-assigned names will avoid the ambiguity you're running into here.

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  serviceA:
    # no image:
    # short form of build: with default dockerfile: and no args:
    build: ${project.basedir}/${project.artifactId}-docker/target
    depends_on:
      - serviceB 

  serviceB:
    # no image:
    build:
      context: ${project.basedir}/${project.artifactId}-docker/target
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile-cloud
```